# Android: Should I Keep images Res Id in business logic entities or UI entities?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-image

I have entities under my business logic.
Each entity can be displayed by an image in the UI logic.
Should I attach each R.Id. (not the image itself!) to the relevant entity in BL, for example:

```
class Entity {
    private int m_imageId; // m_imageId <= R.Id.entity
}
```

or attach entity in UI, for example:

```
class EntityUI extends View {
    void setImage(int image) {
        setImageResource(image);
    }
}
```